# Any way to add labels / tags to a table?

Tags: confluence

I need help with filtering a table based on labels or tags. The issue is that when there are multiple labels, the keywords are not separated properly. Here's an example:

[image]

I have tried using symbols like # or ; to separate the keywords, but they still stick together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality does not seem to be present in Confluence by default. If you use some third-party app, such as Table Filter and Charts for Confluence ([link](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/27447/table-filter-and-charts-for-confluence?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)) you can refer to this vendor support to ask for technical help or to https://community.atlassian.com/